# Binary file reader byte[] to string conversion gone wrong?

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

I'm trying to display whats in the file header which should be text (the rest of the file is binary) but when I print strtemp I get this:

```
strTemp: ??????
```

Here is the code.

```
String fileName = "test.file";

URI logUri = new File(fileName).getAbsoluteFile().toURI();  

BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(logUri))); 

byte[] btemp = new byte[14];
in.read(btemp);

String strtemp = "";

for(int i = 0; i < btemp.length; i+= 2) {
    strtemp += String.valueOf((char)(((btemp[i]&0x00FF)<<8) + (btemp[i+1]&0x00FF)));
}

System.out.println("strTemp: " + strtemp);
```

How do I get strtemp to be whats in the file? and to display it properly?

Comment: Have you tried `new String(btemp)` instead of your loop?

Comment: What's in the file? characters? In which character encoding? How were they written?

Comment: why switch HIGH byte and LOW byte, is it multibyte character? is it little-endian? what's the charset encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the Constructor summary of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html you can initialize a String from bytes directly.

Also you should supply the charset you have in your source file.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of need you can use ByteBuffer and CharBuffer :

```
    FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile("/home/alain/toto.txt", "r").getChannel();
    //Map the 14 first bytes
    ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, 14);
    //Set your charset here
    Charset chars = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    CharBuffer cbuf = chars.decode(buffer);
    System.out.println("str = " + cbuf.toString());
```